# Owl Carousel 2: is there any way to display current item excerpt or item details?

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

My goal is to make a carousel with item title and description that looks like this:

[image]

I want to display current item description under pagination. Is it possible via Owl Carousel 2?

**Here is my code:**

```
$(function(){
        var itemClass = $('#owl-item-carousel');
        itemClass.on('initialized.owl.carousel', function(e){
        var idx = e.item.index;
        $('.owl-item').removeClass('middle');
        $('.owl-item').removeClass('left');
        $('.owl-item').removeClass('right');
        $('.owl-item').removeClass('left-last');
        $('.owl-item').removeClass('right-last');
        $('.owl-item').eq(idx).addClass('middle');
        $('.owl-item').eq(idx-1).addClass('left');
        $('.owl-item').eq(idx+1).addClass('right');
        $('.owl-item').eq(idx-2).addClass('left-last');
        $('.owl-item').eq(idx+2).addClass('right-last');
    });
    $('#owl-item-carousel').owlCarousel({
        center: true,
        items:5,
        loop:true,
        // margin:10,
        pagination: true
    });

    itemClass.on('translate.owl.carousel', function(e){
        idx = e.item.index;
        $('.owl-item').removeClass('middle');
        $('.owl-item').removeClass('left');
        $('.owl-item').removeClass('right');
        $('.owl-item').removeClass('left-last');
        $('.owl-item').removeClass('right-last');
        $('.owl-item').eq(idx).addClass('middle');
        $('.owl-item').eq(idx-1).addClass('left');
        $('.owl-item').eq(idx+1).addClass('right');
        $('.owl-item').eq(idx-2).addClass('left-last');
        $('.owl-item').eq(idx+2).addClass('right-last');
    });
});
```

Above code is only for adding and removing class in item.
**But how can I display current item description under the pagination?**

Comment: Please include a code sample.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a title on an event to have a function update that title. So you could for example:

I would have my markup look like this:

```
<div class="owl-item" data-title="Title-01" data-action="updateTitle"></div>
```

And my JS look would look something like this

```
var $item = $('[data-action=updateTitle]');
$item.bind("click", function(){
     let $this = $(this),
         $dataTitle = $this.data('title'),
         $title = $("#owl-title");

     $title.text($dataTitle)
})
```

Comment: If you are not using es2015(es6) change "let" to "var"

Comment: Thanks for your answers.
Can you please tell me details for more clarification? How can i markup and JS for Slide title and description look like above screenshot?